# Automatic change of color at the set words in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

(English is not my native language)

Hello. It is necessary for me that, for example, a character set `test` in documents which I open by means of Sublime Text 3, was always orange color; `<example>` — always red, `@stackoverflow` — always blue, etc. I want colors, not [highlight](https://github.com/seanliang/HighlightWords). Isn't of great importance for me, will change at once in all color schemes or only in that which I use.

My purpose — I want to have simple ToDo-manager in Sublime Text in which multi-colored words would carry out a role of tags, and on them I could be guided easily. The plug-in [PlainTasks](https://github.com/aziz/PlainTasks) doesn't suit me.

Whether it is possible to paint custom words in certain colors? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Following up on ig0774's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36009719/1426065), here are some concrete examples of what to do. First, create a new file in Sublime with YAML syntax and the following contents:

```yaml
%YAML 1.2
---
# http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html
name: ToDo Manager
file_extensions:
  - todo
scope: text.todo
contexts:
  main:
    - match: (?i)\btest\b
      scope: meta.test
    - match: (?i)\bstackoverflow\b
      scope: meta.stackoverflow
    - match: (?i)\bexample\b
      scope: meta.example
```

You can change the `name` to whatever you want and modify the `file_extensions` for your files. Then, save the file in your `Packages/User` folder (which can be located by selecting **`Preferences -> Browse Packages...`**) as `ToDo Manager.sublime-syntax`.

Now for the color scheme. We'll assume here that you're using the default Monokai color scheme. The actual `.tmTheme` file is wrapped up in a `.sublime-package` archive, so in order to access it you'll need to install the [`PackageResourceViewer`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin. Once installed, open the Command Palette and type in ***prv*** to bring up the PackageResourceViewer options. Select `Edit Package Resource`, navigate to `Color Scheme - Default`, then scroll down and select `Monokai.tmTheme`. If you're using another default color scheme, select that file instead. If you installed a color scheme, open that package first, then select the appropriate `.tmTheme` file.

If the `.tmTheme` file doesn't have syntax highlighting, select XML. Next, scroll down to the very end. The last 5 lines should look something like this:

```xml
    </array>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>06CD1FB2-A00A-4F8C-97B2-60E131912345</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Although the `uuid` likely will be different. Just *before* the `</array>` line, insert the following:

```xml
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>test</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>meta.test</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#FF8000</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>stackoverflow</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>meta.stackoverflow</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#0FD7FF</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>name</key>
            <string>example</string>
            <key>scope</key>
            <string>meta.example</string>
            <key>settings</key>
            <dict>
                <key>background</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>fontStyle</key>
                <string></string>
                <key>foreground</key>
                <string>#FF0000</string>
            </dict>
        </dict>
```

Now, select **`File -> Save`** and it will be saved in the correct place, overriding the file in the `.sublime-package`. Finally, open a `.todo` file and select **`View -> Syntax -> Open all with current extension as... -> User -> ToDo Manager`** and you should see highlighting similar to this:

[image: ToDo Manager]

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a custom syntax to parse the files you create / generate. If you are using SublimeText 3 build 3103 or later you can use the [new `.sublime-syntax`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) file format or for earlier versions, the [`tmLanguage`](http://manual.macromates.com/en/language_grammars#language_grammars) format, which associate scopes to text. Your style file will then associate colours to the scopes you define. It is best to use well-known scopes like those defined under the **Naming Conventions** section in the second link so that, whatever style is defined, you will get some appropriate highlighting.

Slight summary: style files associate appearances with certain scopes. Scopes are defined in syntax files which tell SublimeText what text to match and what scope to associate it with. [Here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/color_schemes.html) is some Sublime-related documentation on the format of style files (`.tmTheme`).

Comment: I apologize, whether it is possible to set a concrete example how I have to carry out changes? For example, I want that the tag `<test>` always was orange, and tag `<stackoverflow>` always blue. I use Sublime Text build 3103. Such simple functions are required for me. Thanks.